# How to create singleton object and using for UI and viewmodel for two screen in kotlin jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, singleton, android-mvvm

I have a list like this

```
 data class SelectedNtrItem(
        val items:ArrayList<NutritionSearchItem> = arrayListOf()
    )
```

I need to use this list on two composable screens, so I need to access a single example of it. My idea is to create it with singelton and use it on the UI and Viewmodel side, but I could not do this completely.

```
class SelectedNtrItemManager {
    companion object{
        private val _selectedNtrItem = MutableStateFlow(SelectedNtrItem())
        val selectedNtrItem: StateFlow<SelectedNtrItem> = _selectedNtrItem.asStateFlow()
    }
}
```

This is the class I created as singelton. How can I use this in the viewmodel and UI side of two composable screens, that is, how can I access this list on both the UI side and the viewmodel side on two screens as a single object because I need the same list?

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: FirstScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
...


@HiltViewModel
class FirstScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
       .... ) : ViewModel() { ....
```

---

```
@Composable
fun SecondScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: SecondScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
...


@HiltViewModel
class SecondScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
       .... ) : ViewModel() { ....
```

**SOLVED**

I solved the problem like below:

```
object SelectedNtrItemManager {

    var selectedItems =  SnapshotStateList<NutritionSearchItem>()

    fun addItem(item: NutritionSearchItem) {
        selectedItems.add(item)
    }

    fun removeItem(item: NutritionSearchItem) {
        selectedItems.remove(item)
    }
}
```

**FirstScreen VM:**

```
 val selectedItems: SnapshotStateList<NutritionSearchItem>
        get() = SelectedNtrItemManager.selectedItems

  fun addSelectedNutritionItem(
       ntrItem: NutritionSearchItem
   ) {
       if (selectedItems.contains(ntrItem)) {
           SelectedNtrItemManager.removeItem(ntrItem)
       } else {
           SelectedNtrItemManager.addItem(ntrItem)
       }
   }
```

**SecondScreen VM**

```
class SecondScreenVM : ViewModel() {

    val list: SnapshotStateList<NutritionSearchItem>
        get() = SelectedNtrItemManager.selectedItems

    fun deleteItemFromList(item: NutritionSearchItem) {
        SelectedNtrItemManager.removeItem(item)
    }
}
```

**SecondScreen UI:**

```
  val list = viewModel.list
  LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)) {
                items(list) { item ->....
```

To detect the changes I made I used SnapshotStateList. SnapshotStateList detects when there is a change and notifies listeners and I updated my SelectedNtrItemManager like above and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Is using the same View model for both screens a viable option? You could combine the two if they aren't too packed and use a single instance of the View model so they both have access to the same variable. This might not be the best option, but I did just that with my settings screen as I only have 5 options and I needed access to each of them in the main screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the ViewModel as follows and pass it as a parameter to the relevant screens.

```
private val sharedViewModel by viewModels<SharedViewModel>()

@Composable
fun FirstScreen(
    viewModel: SharedViewModel
) {
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen(
    viewModel: SharedViewModel
) {
}
```

Comment: Does `ViewModel`s are considered `Stable` by Compose compiler?

Answer (score 1):

I would put the data object into some kind of Repository class that gets injected into both of your ViewModels. There you can collect it as a flow and then collect it in your composable.

```
class Repository {

    val itemListFlow = MutableSharedFlow<SelectedNtrItem>()

}

class FirstScreenViewModel(repository: Repository): ViewModel() {

    val itemListFlow = repository.itemListFlow.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, null)

}

@Composable
fun FirstScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: FirstScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val list by viewModel.itemListFlow.collectAsState()
}

class SecondScreenViewModel(repository: Repository): ViewModel() {

    val itemListFlow = repository.itemListFlow.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, null)

}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: FirstScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val list by viewModel.itemListFlow.collectAsState()
}
```

Comment: How can I use this for second screen ? Can you do what you are trying to do by adding the second screen?

Comment: I edited my answer just do the exact same thing as in your first viewmodel and composable

Comment: it doesnt work.

Comment: What i forgot is you need to declare the Repository as a singleton in Hilt. Im not a hilt expert but i think its just using the @Singleton annotation.